# How can I make a mongoDB schema delete in 5 min

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So im making a verification code sorta thing, they get the code then they can verify. But, I want to make it so it expires in 5 min (so the db isnt filled with random stuff) after creation how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `expireAt` as time-to-live parameter with `createIndex`.

> To create a TTL index, use the createIndex() method on a field whose value is either a date or an array that contains date values, and specify the expireAfterSeconds option with the desired TTL value in seconds.

```js
db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

Document will expire in 1 hour and will be deleted automatically by mongodb.

Check this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) | [TTL indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

**Update:**

In mongoose you can this parameter directly in Schema constructor

```js
const schema = Schema({ name: String, timestamp: Date, metadata: Object }, {
  expireAfterSeconds: 86400
});
```

Comment: How can I do this with MOONGOSE?